# How to change the thread names of the standard JDK corba ORB threadpool

Tags: java, multithreading, corba

Is there away to set the standard jdk corba ORB's thread names used in the default thread pool?

By default there are 3 threads per connections. Their name is useless as they always default to: `p:default-threadpool; w: Idle`. It would be great to change their names mainly for debugging reasons.

Looking at the JDK `com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadpoolManagerImpl` source I can see that the name cannot be accessed from outside the class. At the moment I use the `Thread.currentThread().setName()` to set the thread name once I control the thread but it seems a hack. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the threads that are currently running and rename them as required. Something like:

```
int counter = 1;
for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
  if (t.getName().startsWith("p:default-threadpool")) t.setName("Corba #" + counter++);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about this way. Thanks for that! ... However I am still not able to fully identify the threads and set the right name. More specifically the ORB creates 3 threads per threadpool per connection. That means that if I have 2 connections I will get 6 threads. Unfortunately all 6 have the same name so I can't distinguish which connection they belong to.

Comment: @Kostas I see - I'm not sure how to do that.